# in javascript, how to distinguish between no arg passed and undefined arg passed

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, arguments

within a function, how to discern between a non-arg and an undefined arg?

```
myFunc( 'first' );

var obj = { a: 123 };
myFunc( 'first', obj.b );
_or_
myFunc( 'first', undefined )
```

<strike>`arguments.length` refers to arguments *past* the named arguments, so it's no help</strike>  Can be solved easily with `arguments.length` - sorry about the brain fart!

```
function myFunc( a, b ) {

  // Case A: if no second arg, provide one
  // should be: if( arguments.length < 2 ) ...
  if( b === undefined ) b = anotherFunc;

  // Case B: if b is not resolved - passed but undefined, throw
  else if( b === undefined ) throw( 'INTERNAL ERROR: undefined passed' );

  // Case C: if b not a function, resolve by name
  else if( typeof b != 'function' ) { ... }

  ...
}
```

What is the correct way to capture *Case A* and *Case B* in `myFunc`?

Comment: When would you ever pass `undefined` as a function argument? That is not usual, is it?

Comment: this is a library.  if someone mis-uses it, eg, passing an undefined, wish to raise an error.

Comment: Why do you say `arguments.length` is no help?  See http://jsfiddle.net/4V7FY/

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth cluttering a library with code checking for this occasion. IMO. Why not use the same behaviour in that case like when no argument is passed and be done with it?

Comment: Would it not be better to just handle `undefined` with your Case A (or one of your cases, anyway) every time, regardless of *how* the argument came to be `undefined`?

Comment: It will throw an error automatically I guess because it will fail somewhere in your code.... a solution depends on which are acceptable values for `b`.

Comment: @Ray Toal - Because I was _brain dead_!  Was reading doc on **Dart**, where (as I recall - need to check) `arguments` was those _after_ the named args - _mea culpa_

Comment: In fact, passing undefined should be treated in the same way as not passing the argument, you shouldn't make a difference between the 2.

Comment: @draevor - respectfully disagree.  _not_ passing a second arg is asking for the function to provide the default.  passing an `undefined` second arg is simply a bug.

Comment: @ccyoung Ah, okay, I see.  Well I was going to turn that comment into an answer but (1) Yoshi just did, and (2) I gotta say I agree with draevor that you actually _should not_ try to distinguish this case because the semantics of JavaScript say that when no argument is passed to a parameter, that parameter gets the value `undefined`, which _should be treated the same as having `undefined` explicitly passed_ IMHO. :)  Granted passing `undefined` explicitly is ugly, but maybe the caller is expecting to take advantage of these JavaScript semantics?  Then again, `arguments` exists....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
function myFunc() {
  var a, b;

  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    a = arguments[0];
    console.log('no b passed');
  }
  else if (arguments.length > 1) {
    a = arguments[0];
    b = arguments[1];
    if (b === undefined) {
      console.log('undefined passed as parameter');
    }
  }

  console.log(a, b);
}

myFunc(1);
myFunc(1, undefined);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no cross-browser compatible way to do exactly what you wish. Moreover, I think that a function that changes its behavior when `undefined` is passed explicitly (vs. not passed at all) is confusing. That said, your overall target can be achieved by slightly changing the protocol.

Let's examine how you want my_func to be used:

```
my_func(1) // case A
my_func(1, undefined) // case B
my_func(1, {}.b) // case B
my_func(1, "blah") // case C
```

See my point? Case A can happen only if the caller passes a single argument.

Thus, if you separate `my_func()` into two functions: `my_funcA`, taking a single argument, and `my_funcBC`, taking two arguments, you will be able to implement your logic correctly.

The only change that this inflicts, on the caller of the function, is that if the caller passes a single argument he needs to call `my_funcA()`. In all other casses, `my_funcBC()` should be called.

```
 function my_funcA(a) {
   my_funcBC(a, anotherFunc);
 }

 function my_funcBC(a, b) {
   if (b === undefined) 
     throw( 'INTERNAL ERROR: undefined passed' );

   if (typeof b != 'function') { ... }     
   ...
 }
```